# Finding a minimum value of an expression

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

I have this question to solve:

A city's temperature of y degrees Celsius on a day in February is given by $y = 16 + 8 \sin \left(\dfrac{\pi t}{12}\right)$ where t is the time in hours after 9am.

a). What is the minimum temperature?

b). At what time is the temperature a minimum?

c). What is the temperature at 5pm?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b) $0=y'=\frac{2\pi}{3}\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{12}\right) \Rightarrow t=6 \Rightarrow$ The time at which the temperature is minimal is $3$pm.

(a) In $t=6$, the temperature is minimal. So the minimum temperature is 24 degrees Celsius.

(c) The temperature at 5pm is calculated in $t=8$, ie, $y(8)=16+4\sqrt{3}$.